# issues with linking external pages to my page

Tags: html

I am having issues with jsfiddle not opening the right url I provided. Here is a sample code where I try to link google.com to my page. The problem I am facing that when I click the a tag element it takes me to https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/google.com instead of http://google.com

Here is my work : [code](https://jsfiddle.net/qLatv8o6/)

```
 <a href="google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include full url:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
```

Comment: @AvaLucas tick the tick under the anwser to mark this answer as the correct one :).